# evaluating neural network performance

Tags: r, neural-network, normalization, evaluation

I trained my neural network with a sigmoid activation function so that the predicted values lie in the range [0,1). However, the range of real data in which the z-score transformation has been performed goes beyond [0,1). In this case what would be the appropriate way to evaluate my model. Should I rescale as well the original test data to the same range and then evaluate with criteria like mean square forecast error?

```r
> real_predicted_neural
      predicted        real
1  1.909219e-07 -3.57877473
2  4.161819e-08 -2.28704595
3  1.754706e-11 -1.08509429
4  1.149891e-13 -0.46573114
5  7.777560e-02  0.42381300
6  4.173448e-07 -0.44060297
7  1.119703e-01  0.21075550
8  8.682557e-01 -0.01292402
9  4.736056e-08 -0.29830701
10 7.506821e-08 -1.20302227
11 7.341235e-01 -0.03986571
12 7.501776e-05 -0.94315815
13 1.145697e-04  0.49730175
14 2.214929e-13  0.04252241
15 4.597199e-01 -0.38539901
16 2.324931e-03 -0.74468628
17 4.366025e-06 -0.77037244
18 1.394450e-06  0.16679048
19 5.869884e-11 -0.75876486
20 1.817941e-04  0.04303387
21 7.060773e-04  0.06099372
22 8.267170e-06 -1.21687318
23 9.388680e-02  0.61135319
24 1.099290e-01  0.55715201
25 9.757236e-01 -0.33480226
26 9.544055e-01  0.09061006
27 7.322074e-07  0.09290822
28 1.014327e-06 -0.61658893
29 7.848382e-08 -0.78739456
30 1.791908e-04 -0.44073540
31 1.357918e-03 -0.22099008
32 5.192233e-06 -0.32744703
33 2.624779e-06 -0.37644068
34 6.414216e-02 -0.36947939
35 1.388143e-06 -0.00994845
36 3.010872e-05 -0.05984833
37 9.873201e-03 -0.21815268
38 3.896163e-04 -0.24009094
39 2.718760e-02  0.33383333
40 1.025650e-02  0.09779867
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please could you share a sample of your data? What have you done so far? Could you show us your code and expected output in order to help you?

Comment: Sure, I will then edit my question and repost it, thanks in advance